# Sitecore "Uncaught ReferenceError: MultilistWithSearch is not defined"

Tags: javascript, migration, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore8.1

We are in the process of migrating a customers website from sitecore 7 to sitecore 8.1 initial release.

We have created packages that contain the items from the sitecore 7 instance and installed these packages on the sitecore 8.1 instance.

Now on some items we get the following console error when we click on the node:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MultilistWithSearch is not defined

Has anyone got an idea how we got this error and how we can solve it?

It's really anoying because once you've got this error alot of the actions (like clicking the right mouse button on an item) show the message:

> Please wait while the Content Editor is loading

Comment: Do you packages have files like configs in them or just items? This sound like a config file designed for 7 is in your 8 site. I would use beyond compare and compare your config folders and bin with a Sitecore 8 unzipped site. Making sure your configs or dlls are not coming from 7. There were a lot of changes from 7.2 on the config front.

Comment: Try to exclude Core database items from your packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script cannot be found, you can try to following (based on: [Bug: Sitecore Multilist and Treelist With Search Field Search Not Working Intermittently](https://www.cmsbestpractices.com/bug-sitecore-multilist-and-treelist-with-search-field-search-not-working-intermittently/)).

Add the following lines right before the closing head tag of the editor layout: Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Default.aspx

The relative path to the script is:
/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/Scripts/MultilistwithSearch.js

Comment: It's a bit dirty but I tried this and it actually works.